# subs function for maple function

Tags: maple

I have a problem in working with subs function in maple. Here is my problem.
I have a function.

> psi:=x->c1*exp(sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar*x) + c2*exp(-sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar*x);

Now I want to make it simpler and I want to substitute `sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar=k`.

> subs(sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar=k,psi);

But this operation returns the initial function unchanged. 
Does any one know how to make that substitution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you were working with an expression rather than a procedure for `psi` then you could accomplish that substitution using the `algsubs` command. Ie,

```
psiexpr := c1*exp(sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar*x)    
           + c2*exp(-sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar*x):

simplify(algsubs(sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar=k,psiexpr));

                      c1 exp(x k) + c2 exp(-x k)
```

But it can be much more difficult to substitute into the body of a procedure in general. Neither `eval` not `algsubs` work, and while `subs` can substitute into a procedure body it has two problems with trying that here. The first problem is that `sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar` doesn't exist "on its own" in your procedure `psi`. Ie,

```
psi:=x->c1*exp(sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar*x)
        + c2*exp(-sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar*x):

subs(sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar=k,eval(psi)); # returns unchanged, the same as psi itself
```

The second is that even if you were to try the substitution `hbar=sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/k` then there would be no simplification because the substitution is just syntactic. (And you'd only even want to consider that if hbar only appeared in your target subexpression.) Ie,

```
subs(hbar=sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/k,eval(psi));

                                    1/2
                sqrt(2 m (V0 - E)) 2    k x
x -> c1 exp(1/2 ---------------------------)
                                  1/2
                      (m (V0 - E))

                                       1/2
                   sqrt(2 m (V0 - E)) 2    k x
     + c2 exp(-1/2 ---------------------------)
                                     1/2
                         (m (V0 - E))
```

If that procedure `psi` was not produced by you in the first place, but was returned by some computation, then you could make a function call on it, substitute, and then turn the result back into a procedure. If you really prefer a procedure rather than an expression. Ie,

```
unapply(simplify(algsubs(sqrt(2*m*(V0-E))/hbar=k,psi(x))),x);  

                    x -> c1 exp(x k) + c2 exp(-x k)
```

Of course the above will not work if your original procedure body is complicated (multi-line, or has conditionals, etc) and you are hoping to do syntactic replacement through and through.

It may be relevant to you that, while procedures called one an arbitrary value, expressions can be evaluated at arbitrary values. You'll get the same result here if you do either `psi(3)` or `eval(psiexpr,x=3)`. So you may be able to get by using an expression rather than a procedure, in which case you have a lot more choice of ways to substitute.